# I am getting a Parameter error when previewing my report

Tags: sql, date, dependencies, parameter-passing, forward

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9ddw.jpg)I've created a query and added date parameters withing the query.   When I to run the report, I get the error message

> "The report parameter 'StartDate' has a DefaultValue or a ValidDate
>   that depends on the report parameter "StartDate".  Forward
>   dependencies are not valid.

I have written tons of reports using the same database and same parameters and this has always worked.   I worked for a different company now that uses the same ERP software as my previous employer, so I'm not sure what the difference is.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and SQL 2014

```
WHERE (invoicedate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate)
```

My parameter settings are set to use Date/Time under General, and Get values from a query under Available values.   There are no default values indicated.

Comment: Sounds like a cascading issue. Are you sure the order of the parameters in you report is matching with the order in Stored Procedure (or SQL script)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a cascading-related problem. Make sure the type of the variables match, as they both should be `date`, `datetime` or `string`. Also, please do:

1- Ensure the order of the parameters in your report completely matches with the order in your SQL Script. Example: If `@param1=startDate` and `@param2=EndDate` in the report, then make sure the Script takes startDate first as @param1 and then EndDate as @param2.

2- If EndDate is based on StartDate (like `EndDate=DateAdd(month,2,StartDate`), then make sure you take StartDate before then EndDate.

3- Remove default values (if any) defined in SSRS, but set it in your SQL Script.

Also, if you are using "cascading parameters", this is a good source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/aa337169(v=sql.105)

Comment: This is a date for sure.  It is only one column, which is the invoice date, so basically the parameters allow the user to select the first invoice date and last.  I.E to get sales for one month, one year, on day etc.   The start date is before the end date in the list, and there are no defaults.

Comment: @Jetta can you try to run a SQL Profiler on the SQL server, enabling Error columns ON, and execute the SQL Report after that? You can see the query on the Profiler, then try to run the same query yourself on a SQL Window, you'll be able to debug the error. Did you use SQL Profiler before?

Comment: Also, could you please send a screenshot of your SSRS design, showing all the parameters? Did you try to change the order of the parameters in you report and execute the report?

Comment: I added a screen shot, although it may not be what you are looking for.   In the profiler, the report didn't return any errors